# How can I write a reducer/action creator combo to update state on button click?

Tags: react-redux

I'm creating a set of team cards that level-up/level-down on button click. The cards render based on the state, which is an array. I'm not sure what the code inside the action creator and reducer should be to do this.

What works:

1. The cards render correctly with the right data from the state, using state.map() and mapStateToProps()
2. The LEVEL_UP action dispatches on click as I can see it in the redux dev tools

What doesn't work:

1. The action doesn't actually do anything yet
2. Everything I've tried leads to undefineds, so I'm having trouble accessing the right data in the reducer

```
**TeambuilderCards.js** 

import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import TeamBuilderCard from "./TeamBuilderCard.js";

const TeamBuilderCards = ({ teamMembers }) => {
  return (
    <div className="ui centered cards">
      {teamMembers.map(teamMember => (
        <TeamBuilderCard
          key={teamMember.id}
          name={teamMember.name}
          xp={teamMember.xp}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    teamMembers: state
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TeamBuilderCards);
```

```
**Teambuildercard.js**

import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { levelUp, levelDown } from "../actions";

const roundUp = num => Math.ceil(num / 100) * 100;

const TeamBuilderCard = (props, dispatch) => (
  <div className="ui card">
    <div className="content">
      <div className="header">{props.name}</div>
      <div className="description">
        <h3>Current Level: {props.xp.toString().slice(0, 1)}</h3>
        <p>XP is currently {props.xp}</p>
        <p> {roundUp(props.xp) - props.xp} xp points to to next level</p>
      </div>
      <div className="meta">
        Increase or decrease {props.name}'s level with the buttons below
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="extra content">
      <div className="ui two buttons">
        <div className="ui basic green button" onClick={props.levelUp}>
          Level up
        </div>
        <div className="ui basic pink button" onClick={props.levelDown}>
          Level down
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = { levelUp, levelDown };

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TeamBuilderCard);
```

```
**actions.js**

export const LEVEL_UP = "LEVEL_UP";
export const LEVEL_DOWN = "LEVEL_DOWN";

export function levelUp() {
  return { type: LEVEL_UP };
}

export function levelDown() {
  return { type: LEVEL_DOWN };
}
```

```
**reducers/index.js**

import { LEVEL_UP, LEVEL_DOWN } from "../actions";
import preloadedState from "../preloadedState"; *//preloadedState is and array and I want to modify state[i].xp*

const initialState = preloadedState;

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LEVEL_UP:
      return state; *//want to add 100 XP*
    case LEVEL_DOWN:
      return state; *//want to subtract 100 XP*
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```
*preLoadedState.js* //Just the first 3 objects in the array

const preloadedState = [
  {
    id: "0",
    name: "Pete",
    xp: 153
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Jane",
    xp: 121
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Jim",
    xp: 188
  }

];

export default preloadedState;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the previous answer, which I accepted returned some errors in the console about mutating the state. There was also a warning about non- serializable data. That was solved by ignoring the check in react-starter-kit's configureStore().

However, this now works as planned with no errors in the console, but still big thanks because all the rest of hagai harari's suggestions did the trick.

```
import preloadedState from "../preloadedState";

export const reducer = (state = preloadedState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LEVEL_UP":
      return state.map((xpUp, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, xpUp, {
            xp: state[action.index].xp + 100
          });
        }
        return xpUp;
      });
    case "LEVEL_DOWN":
      return state.map((xpDown, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, xpDown, {
            xp: state[action.index].xp - 100
          });
        }
        return xpDown;
      });
    case "ERROR":
      console.log("There has been an error, ", action.err);
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

import and use ladash map to loop through array of objects

Reducers :

```
import map from 'lodash/map'

case LEVEL_UP:
      let nextstate = map(preloadedState,(eachobject,index)=>{
          let xp = eachobject.xp 
          eachobject.xp = xp + 100; 
      })
      return nextstate;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Couldn't solve the initial problem but solved a different one instead.

Answer (score 0):

for my opinion the best way to do that it to add the math at the reducer -

---

```
export const reducer = (state = preloadedState, action) => {
  let newState = [...state] // now we can manipulate newState
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LEVEL_UP':
        newState[action.index].xp = state[action.index].xp + 100
        return newState
    case 'LEVEL_DOWN':
       newState[action.index].xp = state[action.index].xp - 100
        return newState
    case 'ERROR':
        console.log('has been error, ', action.err)
        return state
    default:
        return state
  }
}
```

---

do notice, I am using the index in the array of the called user to add/decrease XP from the right user.

---

```
/create one action for example

export const levelUp = index => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: 'LEVEL_UP',
            index
        })
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'ERROR',
            err
        })

      }
  }
 }
```

---

and the last things that we need to do is send the index/whatever you gonna change accord from the frontend

---

```
   <div className="ui basic green button" onClick={()=>props.levelUp(index)}> //you should define the index here
      Level up
    </div>
```

Comment: Wonderful!  Thanks so much for this. Works beautifully.